# How to remove the error message no internet connection

Tags: android, android-studio

i use this code to display a internet page with WebView :

```
class lapagewebview : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lapagewebview)

        val mywebview:WebView=findViewById(R.id.lapagevisitevirt)
        mywebview.webViewClient= object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view: WebView?, url: String? ): Boolean {
               view?.loadUrl(url?: String())
               return true
            }
            }
        var lapage = getIntent().getStringExtra("lapage")
        mywebview.loadUrl("${lapage}")
        mywebview.settings.javaScriptEnabled=true
        mywebview.settings.allowContentAccess=true
        mywebview.settings.domStorageEnabled=true
        mywebview.settings.useWideViewPort=true
        mywebview.settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true)

    }

}
```

the problem is when there is an internet problem or something else I have this message:

```
WebPage not available... The webpage http:.... could not be loaded because Err internet disconnected
```

What I want is that this message does not appear, a blank page preferably or another solution without calling a page on the internet.
Thank you

Comment: before loading image check the internect connection and if its connected than open it else show a blank view or a message internect connection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55437061/how-to-show-no-internet-connection-dialog-in-webview-android-studio

Comment: @Amitpandey this is my code : who to display a blank page ?
if(testconnct.noconnection(this)){
            //who to display blank page ?
        }else{
            view?.loadUrl(url?: String())
        }

Comment: just hide the webview in if and you will able to see the blank view